# Determining the cause of kubernetes pod restart

Tags: c++, docker, kubernetes

I'm running into issues with our Kubernetes deployment. Recently we are running into a problem with one of the pods being restarted frequently.

The service inside is using C++, with Google Logging and should dump a stacktrace on a crash (it does do that when run locally).

Unfortunately, the only log message I was able to find, related to the pod restart is from `containerd`, just saying "shim reaped".

Do I need to turn on some extra logging/monitoring to have the reasons for restart retained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pod could have been terminated for reasons like out of memory. Use `kubectl describe pod <podname>` which contains the information.

There should be output like this (could also be a different reason than OOM):

```
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
```

Comment: Ok, this was helpful. `Reason: Error Exit Code: 141`. No idea what is exit code 141, but at least I made some progress :-D

Comment: @Šimon-tóth , Have you been checking the https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/ ? Will it work in your case?  I'm looking for an explanation for err141 in k8s codebase, but can't see any.

Answer (score 6):

Your can check crashed pod log by running

```
$ kubectl logs -f <pod name> -n <namespace> --previous
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the log seems to indicate normal operation :-/